# How to specify column format in SELECT INTO statements in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table `[TABLE1]` with columns `A`, `B`, `C` for example. Already have data inside. There is a new column, say `B2`, that I want to add into a new table `[TABLE2]`.

Due to weird permission setup , I can create table, I can `SELECT INTO`, but I cannot change the columns settings.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT A, B, '' as B2, C
INTO TABLE2
FROM TABLE1;
```

This give us more or less what I want.  But `B2` is now `varchar(1)`.  I want to specify it to be `varchar(5)` within the above code. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to the type you want:

```
SELECT A, B, CAST('' as VARCHAR(5)) as B2, C
```